# Will vs Be going to

Tags: will-vs-going-to

You don’t study hard for the exam. You‘re going to be failed tomorrow.

1. What would it mean with "WILL" rather than "ARE GOING TO"? Because WILL can also be used for prediction, make a guess as well as definite (sure) actions in the future.
2. And why "to be failed"? What would be the difference with "fail"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using "will" in the stead of "are going to" is fine, as in "You will be failed, tomorrow."  One of its meanings is as you say.
2. "To be failed," such as if a professor said, "I'm going to fail you" (thus you will be failed) is a colloquial construction to replace something like, "I'm going to give you a failing grade."  The second construction is obviously longer, hinting at the reason the colloquial construction was created.  "To be failed" is technically incorrect *in this sentence*, in other words, but such is the way of colloquialisms.

   I should say, though, your question presents the first I've heard of this usage.  If a professor said they would fail someone, the other person would not say, "I'm going to be failed."  They would say something like, "The professor said he'd fail me."